# Erro ao configurar app do Facebook

Tags: facebook, login

Há cerca de 8 meses atrás eu configurei o login pelo Facebbok no meu plugin Wordpress (Yith Social Login) e estava tudo ocorrendo normalmente.

Porém de uma hora para outra parou de funcionar, não entendi o motivo. Também tentei deletar ele e criar um novo app, chaves e id tudo configurado, porém o erro que me retorna é:

**Não é possível carregar a URL: O domínio dessa URL não está incluído nos domínios do aplicativo. Para poder carregar essa URL, adicione todos os domínios e subdomínios ao campo Domínios do aplicativo nas configurações do aplicativo.**

Coloquei já:

- Domínios do aplicativo
- URL do site na plataforma web

E o pior é que a comunidade do suporte do Facebook não está abrindo (pelo menos pra mim).